# Control-M Prerequisites - Make job dependent on server availability

Tags: control-m

I want to know if I can add pre-requisite conditions for a job based on server availability. Suppose Job J runs from job server JS, and it interacts with two other servers SERVER1 and SERVER2.

I want to configure job J such that it runs only when SERVER1 and SERVER2 are available. In case any of the two servers is down, the job should wait for servers to come back online.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this should be a comment or an answer, but what you are looking for is not natively available within Control-M.

The simplest solution I can think for you is to configure a sleep job to run on SERVER1 and SERVER2 and have them as pre-decessors to job J. These sleep jobs will only run when the agents on SERVER1/2 are available therefore confirming server availability prior to execution of job J.

Alternatively you could write a script that loops waiting for SERVER1/2 to respond to pings then complete and configure this job as a pre-decessor to job J.

Comment: Actually there are 100s fo jobs running on the server, so connecting to a sleep job might be too much of an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still newbie in Control-M but we have implemented a solution with similar goals with a job hook to proof nodes.

Assumed, your target server (node) called JS which interacts with SERVER1 (let's call node01). Any number of servers / nodes can be added later, let's see with just one node.

Overview components:

- Jobs created for monitor changes and check status while OK and NOT OK status
- Quantitative resource created for each node, for example *node01_run* (or stacked, as you wish)
- Jobs are containing quantitative resource "node01_run" with least 1 free resource
- If everything ok, jobs should run as expected
- If downtime is recognized, quantitative resource (QR) will be changed to 0, so affected jobs should not run,
- If the node is up again, quantitative resource will be set to the original value (10, 100, 1000, ...) and the jobs should run again as usual

**Job name: node01_check_resource**

```
Job Goal  --->  Check if quantitative resource already existing
Job OS Command  --->  ecaqrtab LIST node01_run
Result yes  --->  do nothing,
Result no  --->  Job node01_create_resource, command: ecaqrtab ADD node01_run 100 (or as many as you wish)
```

**Job name: node01_check (cyclic)**

```
Job Goal  --->  Check if node up
Job OS Command  --->  As you define that you node is up: check webservice, check uptime, wmi result, ping, ...
Result up  --->  rerun job in x minutes
Result no  --->  go for next job
```

**Job name: node01_up-down**

```
Job Goal  --->  Case for switching between status up and status down
Job OS Command  --->  ecaqrtab UPDATE node01_run 0
On-Do action:  --->  when job ended, remove condition that node01_check cannot start (as is defined as cyclic job)
```

**Job name: node01_check_down (cyclic)**

```
Job Goal  --->  Check status while known status is down
Job OS Command  --->  As defined in node01_check
Result down  --->  Do nothing as job is defined as cyclic
Result up  --->  Remove some contitions
```

**Job name: node01_down-up**

```
Job Goal  --->  Switching all back to normal operation
Job OS Command  --->  ecaqrtab UPDATE node01_run 100
Action  --->  Add condition that node01_check can run again
```

You can define such job hooks for multiple nodes and you can define in each job, which nodes should be up and running (means where the quantitative resource is higher than 0). It can be monitored multiple hosts and still set the same resource - as you wish.

I hope this helps further, unless you have found a suitable solution already.